# Dynamically access state while integrating (python)

Tags: scipy, odeint

I am integrating a system using scipy's odeint.

I would like to access the state during integration, and use it in the next step in the integration to modify the state accordingly.
More specifically, I want to take a dot product of the previous state and current state, and if it satisfies a certain condition I may want to alter the current state. This has effect on the next step of the integration, etc...

I am not sure how I can do this. That is, I want to dynamically access my state during the integration routine and modify it accordingly.

EDIT: In MATLAB there is an argument "outputFcn" which might be useful. I am essentially looking for an outputFcn type solution in Python.

Comment: `odeint` solves a system of ordinary differential equations, where the independent variable (often interpreted as the time *t*) is assumed to be continuous.  In the mathematical model, the state varies smoothly as a function of the independent variable, so there is no well-defined meaning of "previous state" and "next state" for this problem.

Comment: The numerical method used to solve the problem uses discrete increments of finite size, but the size of those steps is variable (the underlying solver in `odeint` uses an adaptive, variable step method), so the notion of "previous" and "next" states is still not really meaningful.  Can you better explain the mathematical formulation of the problem that you are trying to solve?  An ODE solver might not be the right tool for it.